# Converting from string to int?

Tags: c#

I've just started out with coding and I'm looking at making a simple Higher/Lower game.
I have a random start number, and a new number set up when the 'higher' or 'lower' buttons are clicked. What I want to say though is....

If the person clicks the higher button: If `NewNumberLbl` is greater than round1numberlbl. then do something. Thing is im getting the issue of not being able to say

```
If {NewNumberLbl.Text > Round1NumberLbl.Text}
{}
```

because I'm getting the error:

> Error    1   Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

so how do I go about fixing this and making it into a type int?

Ps I was trying to create new int's , associate them with the ints within the random number methods and then call them instead?

HELP!

```
public Round1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    RandomNumber(0, 12);
    NewNumberLbl.Visible = true;
}

public void RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    int num = new Random().Next(min, max);
    Round1NumberLbl.Text = num.ToString();
}

public void RandomNumber2(int min, int max)
{
    int num2 = new Random().Next(min, max);
    NewNumberLbl.Text = num2.ToString();
}

private void Round1HBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //RandomNumber2(0, 12);
    //if (newNumber >= originalNumber) 
    //{

    //}
}
```

Comment: Are you seriously telling me you couldn't look this up on Google (or on StackOverflow)?

Comment: Few hints: use numeric data type such as int to compare the values using operators such as < and >. Also, let your methods return an int instead of void and use that result. Also, your 2 methods are almost identical. Try to use only one.

Answer (score 3):

Converting a string to a int:

```
int i;
if (int.TryParse("1234", out i){
    //ok
}
```

Comment: I like using the TryParse as it adds some defense in case the string is contains characters other than a number.  I posted a good MSDN reference in my answer the OP should read and digest.  +1 for first answer peer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
Convert.ToInt32(myString);
```

or:

```
int myOut;
int.TryParse(myString, out myOut);
```

The first one will throw an exception if you try to convert something thats not parseable in an int.

The second one will result in 0 if the conversion is not successful

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx
Try this:-
Convert.ToInt32(input);

Example:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(LblnewNumber.Text) >= Convert.ToInt32(LbloriginalNumber.Text)) 
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

int.Parse(NewNumberLbl.Text);

You should however make sure the label has a number and not some other character.

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = "500";
int num = int.Parse(text);
```

This should work. And you can use TryParse to check "text" is valid